# Is there a way to reuse Sockets in java to avoid allocating memory for new TCP connections?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to build a simple forwarding server in java that allocates only a minimal amount of memory and hits gc rarely if ever. I can use preallocated buffers to copy the data to and from the output and input streams, but each new connection seems to allocate around 10k of memory. Is there a simple way to reuse Socket objects after their connections are closed to avoid this (this is assuming Sockets do not internally need to allocate additional memory if they are reused)?

To clarify, by 'Socket' I am referring to the java class, not the generic notion of a socket. And by 'reuse', I mean that I want to reuse the memory that was allocated by the object to avoid having to reclaim that memory through garbage collection. The motivation for this is to create a simple, highly-responsive server that will not need to pause for garbage collection (I know I could use C/C++ or a proprietary JVM, but I'm trying to explore this solution as a possibility).

Comment: Yes. It's called connection pooling.

Comment: Shouldn't Java's garbage collector free up the memory of the closed Sockets after they are no longer referenced by anything?  If so, the 10k of memory that old sockets took up should be returned to the free-memory pool and there shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: Yes, but I want to avoid GC pauses.

Comment: Why? When you close a socket, all its resources are released, and when you open a new one they are all allocated. There is no saving. What's the point? Not that it's possible.

Comment: You might be able to reuse the object's memory rather than produce garbage and eventually require a garbage collection that would pause the JVM for a short period of time. For example, a regex matcher can be reused in java.

Comment: @jonderryn Well you might be able to reuse the memory but you can't. GC doesn't pause the JVM. The downvote is because it isn't a real question.

Comment: GCs pause most JVMs (see Google). I don't understand why you don't think this is a real question. If I want to write a pause-free forwarding server in java I need to allocate only a finite amount of memory and reuse memory from request to request and from connection to connection. I can easily do the former, but nos' answer suggests it is not possible to do the latter and this answers my question.

Comment: I don't need Google to tell me about Java. GC used to pause VMs in the 1990s but those days are long gone. I haven't seen a GC pause this centypury.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a Socket cannot be reused in Java once it is closed.

Comment: @jonderry Yes. Connection pooling is a technique to reuse active connections. Once a connection is closed/broken/down, you cannot reuse its Socket object anymore for an other/new connection.

Comment: And a socket cannot be reused in any language after it is closed.